# Use v-for key outside of the loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple `v-for` that renders a list of items inside a select box like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" v-model="tableStyle">
            <option v-for="(item,key) in tableStyles">
                {{ item }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Then I have a button that should remove a specific item, the **selected one**. I want to access its key so I can remove it easily. How can I do that? At the moment my key is `undefined`. Can I use `v-model` for that?

```
<button @click="removeStyle(key)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `option` is selected from the `select` element, and it has `v-model` binded to something (`tableStyle` in your case) the `value` attribute of the selected `option` element will be assigned there. So, you can bind `value` to the `key`:

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="tableStyle">
    <option v-for="(item,key) in tableStyles" v-bind:value="key">
        {{ item }}
    </option>
</select>
```

And then you can use your `tableStyle`:

```
<button @click="removeStyle(tableStyle)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>
</button>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hy21um75/

Answer (score 0):

I check your code and it is just incomplete. For that reason, I want to give some clarifications to improve your understanding about how a Vue instance works.

First, remember that the HTML tag `select` uses the `option` tag for each item of the `tableStyles`. Now, this `option` tag should has a `value` parameter and a `text` like in this structure:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">Style 01</option>
  ...
  <option value="3">Style 04</option>
</select>
```

Now, what we need is a way of assigning each key of the array `tableStyles` to each parameter `value` of the `option` tag and rendering the style name of the array `tableStyles` as the `text` of the `option` tag.

```
<option v-for="(item, key) in tableStyles" :value="key">
  {{item}}
</option>
```

Also, do not forget about `v-model` directive, which creates two-way data bindings on form elements. This means, it automatically picks the correct way to update the element based on the input type. We can achieve this by adding `selected` to the data definition in the `Vue` instance creation and adding`v-model="selected"` to the `select` tag.

Ok Teocci, **but why I got `undefined` for my parameter `key` called in the `onClick` event in the `button` tag?**

Well that is because key only is `defined` inside of the `v-for` scope and this scope is defined by the `option` tag.

**Then, how can I get the selected key out of the `v-for` scope?**

Easy, just use `selected` that is defined in all the scope of the `selector` tag as shown in this snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#selector',
  data: {
    selected: '',
    tableStyles: ['Style 01', 'Style 02', 'Style 03', 'Style 04'],
  },
  methods: {
    removeStyle: function(key) {
      this.tableStyles.splice(key, 1);
    },
  },
});
```

```css
#selector .main{
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50%;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 16px !important;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="selector">
  <div class="main">
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected">
      <option v-for="(item, key) in tableStyles" :value="key">
        {{ item }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
  <button @click="removeStyle(selected)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger">Remove</span></button>
  </div>  
  <div class="main">
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
  </div> 
</div>
```